# Why the ```onClick``` JSX event is triggered twice in React without an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick, jsx

When I want to trigger something with the *onClick* JSX event.

With the arrow function the event is triggered once

`<button onClick={() => console.log("This button was clicked")}>Click Me!</button>`

But without the arrow function the event is triggered twice

`<button onClick={console.log("This button was clicked")}>Click Me!</button>`

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: You're running the function in the render call. You are not passing the function to onClick.

Comment: The duplicate question is old but the reason and hence the explanation, answers are still the same.

Comment: the proper way is to use the arrow function